# How can you append to a bash array of strings with heredoc

Tags: arrays, bash, heredoc

I need to create a bunch of strings using heredocs which I want to store in an array so that I can run them all through processes later. For example

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' data  << END
{
"my": "first doc"
}
END

IFS='' read -r -d '' data  << END
{
"my": "second doc"
}
END
```

I know I could append to an array of docs using a construction like

```
docs+=("${data}")
```

after each heredoc, but is there a slick way I can do it directly in the read command without assigning index values (so I can change the order, add others in the middle, etc without it being awkward)?

Comment: If you're trying to process JSON, you should use `jq` rather than bash arrays.

Comment: BTW, note that because your heredocs don't end in NULs but `read -d ''` reads up to the next NUL, your `read` commands have nonzero exit status, so if this code were run with `set -e` (which is [bad practice anyhow](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)) it would fail upon reaching them.

Comment: I'm a huge jq fan, but the docs are created in a way that would be awkward with jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy approach is to build a function that uses namevars to refer to your destination array indirectly.

Note that namevars are a feature added in bash 4.3; before that release, it's not as easy to have the variable be parameterized without getting into unpleasantries like `eval`, so you might end up just hardcoding `data` as your destination if you want portability (and that makes sense in the context at hand).

```
append_to_array() {
  declare -n _dest="$1"
  _dest+=( "$(</dev/stdin)" )
}

append_to_array data <<'END'
{
"my": "first doc"
}
END

append_to_array data <<'END'
{
"my": "second doc"
}
END
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/9zEMWs

Comment: BTW, note the use of `<<'END'` instead of `<<END` -- quoting the heredoc sigil prevents contents of that heredoc from being treated as shell syntax, should there be content able to be parsed as command substitutions / variable expansions / etc. It's thus preferable whenever there isn't a specific need for such expansions.

Comment: It turns out I could get away with function alone without the namevar (e.g.`append_to_array() { myarray+=( "$(</dev/stdin)" )}` for my use. However, learning about namevars as well as the quoting to avoid expansion was very helpful